# Laravel Backpack CRUD not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-backpack

i followed [this](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-example) tutorial to setup a CRUD example. But i can't get it to work and i don't know why. here is my code

SomeitemCrudController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;

// VALIDATION: change the requests to match your own file names if you need form validation
use App\Http\Requests\SomeitemRequest as StoreRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\SomeitemRequest as UpdateRequest;

class SomeitemCrudController extends CrudController
{

    public function setUp()
    {
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | BASIC CRUD INFORMATION
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */
        $this->crud->setModel("App\Models\Someitem");
        $this->crud->setRoute("admin/someitem");
        $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('someitem', 'someitems');

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | BASIC CRUD INFORMATION
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */

        $this->crud->setFromDb();

        // $this->crud->setColumns(['nama']);
        $this->crud->addField([
            'nama' => 'Nama',
            'keterangan' => 'Keterangan',
            'harga' => 'Harga'
        ]);
    }

    public function store(StoreRequest $request)
    {
        $redirect_location = parent::storeCrud();
        return $redirect_location;
    }

    public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
    {
        $redirect_location = parent::updateCrud();
        return $redirect_location;
    }
}
```

the model, Someitem.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Backpack\CRUD\CrudTrait;

class SomeItem extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;
    //

    protected $table = 'someitem';
    protected $fillable = ['nama', 'keterangan', 'harga'];
    public $timestamps = true;
}
```

the request, SomeitemRequest.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class SomeitemRequest extends \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Requests\CrudRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return \Auth::check();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // 'name' => 'required|min:5|max:255'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation attributes that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function attributes()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation messages that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

and then, the routes

```
<?php

Route::group([
    'prefix' => config('backpack.base.route_prefix', 'admin'),
    'middleware' => ['admin'],
    'namespace' => 'Admin'
], function() {
    CRUD::resource('pelayanan', 'Admin\PelayananCrudController');
    Route::get('/test', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});
```

i can access `http://localhost/myapp/public/admin/test` successfully, but i can't access `http://localhost/myapp/public/admin/someitem` , it always return Error 500

i'm new to laravel (and PHP), any helps is appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Why do you addField nama in your controller... Since you did setFromDb() it will be duplicated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to make my answer very detailed, so that's why I've started it from the beginning. The version for backpack CRUD I use is ^3.2.

1. look at this file `your-project/vendor/backpack/crud/src/CrudServiceProvider.php`
   Yes I know that class name is not `CRUD` but `CrudServiceProvider`. That is because they have `register` method in `CrudServiceProvider` and in it  they do `$loader->alias('CRUD', \Backpack\CRUD\CrudServiceProvider::class);` which makes `CRUD` class alias to `CrudServiceProvider`. To know more about how it works inside read through Laravel [Service Providers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/providers), [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container) and [Facades](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/facades).
2. So we've figured out that `CRUD::resource()` actually means `CrudServiceProvider::resource()`, so get to this method, there you will find only one line `return new CrudRouter($name, $controller, $options);` as far as I know (if I'm wrong correct me) it's called [Factory pattern/method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). So go to `CrudRouter` constructor ([Github](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/78197595e1d8a00352e839bc0667b5af662606e3/src/CrudRouter.php#L15)). Read through it. So the basic thing it does is instead of this

   `CRUD::resource('pelayanan', 'Admin\PelayananCrudController');`

it will put something like this

```
Route::post('pelayanan/search', [
        'as' => 'crud.pelayanan.search',
        'uses' => 'Admin\PelayananCrudController@search',
    ]);

    Route::get('pelayanan/reorder', [
        'as' => 'crud.pelayanan.reorder',
        'uses' => 'Admin\PelayananCrudController@reorder',
    ]);

    Route::post('pelayanan/reorder', [
        'as' => 'crud.pelayanan.save.reorder',
        'uses' => 'Admin\PelayananCrudController@saveReorder',
    ]);

    Route::get('pelayanan/{id}/details', [
        'as' => 'crud.pelayanan.showDetailsRow',
        'uses' => 'Admin\PelayananCrudController@showDetailsRow',
    ]);

    Route::get('pelayanan/{id}/translate/{lang}', [
        'as' => 'crud.pelayanan.translateItem',
        'uses' => 'Admin\PelayananCrudController@translateItem',
    ]);

    Route::get('pelayanan/{id}/revisions', [
        'as' => 'crud.pelayanan.listRevisions',
        'uses' => 'Admin\PelayananCrudController@listRevisions',
    ]);

    Route::post('pelayanan/{id}/revisions/{revisionId}/restore', [
        'as' => 'crud.pelayanan.restoreRevision',
        'uses' => 'Admin\PelayananCrudController@restoreRevision',
    ]);
```

You said that you can't acces you `public/admin/someitem` and that's true, because you don't have route for it (actually check routes in cli with `artisan route:list`). But Backpack developers made one thing (don't actually know why) they put extra routes in [destructor](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/78197595e1d8a00352e839bc0667b5af662606e3/src/CrudRouter.php#L61) method by calling

```
`Route::resource($this->name, $this->controller, $options_with_default_route_names);`.
```

And by it should actually work, if it's not, check how `index` (CrudController) behaves.

One more thing maybe you forgot to `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Backpack\Base\BaseServiceProvider"` and you don't have view files and that's why you get 500 error.

If you have more questions, just ask.

Comment: I am using "backpack/base": "^1.1","backpack/crud": "^4.0" and facing same route not found issue, i checked with command artisan route:list but backpack's route not in the list